# Changed the domain on a site and need to add new analytics code but keep stats

Tags: google-analytics

I placed Google Analytics code on a site. However the domain was changed. It is being directed to the new domain. I don't want to lose all the data that has been accumulated.

Can I add the new domain's Google Analytics code and keep the old code in place?

Answer (score 0):

Data is locked to the analytics tracking id code it was collected on. The tracking code can be placed on your new website and continuity will be maintained. i.e. reuse your old code - do not create a new one.